# Iterate through all combinations in Gray code order

Tags: c++, algorithm

Let's say i have *n* integers in an array *a*, and i want to iterate through all possible subsets of these integers, find the *sum*, and then do something with it.

What i immedieatelly did, was to create a bit field *b*, which indicated which numbers were included in the subset, and iterate through its possible values using `++b`. Then, to compute the sum in each step, i had to iterate through all bits like this:

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    if (b&1<<i)
        sum += a[i];
```

Then i realized that if i iterated through the possible values of *b* in a Gray code order, so that each time only a single bit is flipped, i wouldn't have to reconstruct the sum completely, but only needed to add or subtract the single value that is being added or removed from the subset. It should work like this:

```
int sum = 0;
int whichBitToFlip = 0;
bool isBitSet = false;
for (int k = 0; whichBitToFlip < n; k++) {
    sum += (isBitSet ? -1 : 1)*a[whichBitToFlip];

    // do something with sum here

    whichBitToFlip = ???;
    bool isBitSet = ???;
}
```

But i can't figure out how to directly and efficiently compute *whichBitToFlip*. The desired values are basically sequence [A007814](https://oeis.org/A007814). I know that i can compute the Gray code using the formula `(k>>1)^k` and xor it with the previous one, but then i need to find the position of the changed bit, which might not be much faster.

So is there any better way to determine these values (index of flipped bit), preferably without a cycle, faster than recomputing the whole sum (of at most 64 values) every time?

Comment: [Gray code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i came up with this:

```
int sum = 0;
unsigned long grayPos = 0;
int graySign = 1;
for (uint64 k = 2; grayPos < n; k++) {
    sum += graySign*a[grayPos];

    // Do something with sum

    #ifdef _M_X64
        grayPos = n;
        _BitScanForward64(&grayPos, k);
    #else
        for (grayPos = 0; !(k&1ull<<grayPos); grayPos++);
    #endif
    graySign = 2-(k>>grayPos&0x3);
}
```

It works really well, brought down the execution time (in comparison to always recomputing the whole sum) from 254 to  only 7 seconds for *n* = 32. I also found that counting trailing zeroes with the for cycle is only slightly (~15%) slower than using `_BitScanForward64` for the reasons mentioned by rici. So thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To convert a bitmask to a bit index, you can use the `ffs` function (if you have one), which corresponds to a machine opcode on some machines.

Otherwise, the bit changed in the gray code corresponds to the ruler function:

```
0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 1...
```

for which there is a simple recursion. You can simulate the recursion with a stack (it will have maximum depth O(log N), so it's not much space), but probably `ffs` is a lot faster.

(By the way, even if you were to count bits one at a time from right-to-left, the increment function would be `O(1)` on average because the total number of trailing 0s in the integers from 1 to 2<sup>k</sup> is 2<sup>k</sup>-1.)

Comment: I just realized that i don't need to xor the gray codes, because i can get the "ruler function" just from counting the trailing zeroes of `k`, right? Also thanks for the last part, i didn't think of that.